# Auto Covariance of Square Law Detector

Tags: probability, random-variables

if $X(t)$ is Zero Mean WSS Gaussian Random Process , Find the Auto Covariance of $$Y(t)=X^2(t)$$

we have $$E(Y(t))=E(X^2(t))=E(X^2(t+\tau))=R_X(0)$$

$$C_Y(\tau)=R_Y(\tau)-R_X^2(0)$$

$$R_Y(\tau)=E(X^2(t)X^2(t+\tau))$$ I am unable to proceed from here, Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: is $X(t)$ white?

Comment: No $X(t)$ not white..

Comment: Any Help please..

Comment: What about using the fact that $Y$ is $\chi^2$-distributed?

Comment: Yes but its difficult to find Product Distribution of two $\chi^2$ Random Variables...

Comment: According to Alberto Leon Garcia book $$E(X^2(t_1)X^2(t_2))=E(X^2(t_1))E(X^2(t_2))+2\left(E(X(t_1)X(t_2)\right)^2$$...I am unable to derive this